# SQL requery same table

Tags: sql, filter, subquery

I have a table that has a bunch of information:

Part Number, Category, Value, FreqL, FreqH, FREQ1, FREQ2.

I am trying to filter based on a user entry... Say they put in Part Number "xzy"

```
SELECT backup.Value, backup.FREQ1, backup.FREQ2
FROM backup
WHERE ((backup.[Part Number]) ="xyz";
```

I want to requery the table, but also include parts that fit all the same values resulting from xyz query.

I thought of using IN before my subquery, but that only limits to one column, how do i do all three?

Of course the below isn't working >

```
SELECT backup.[Part Number], backup.Value, backup.FreqL, backup.FreqH
FROM backup 
WHERE (backup.Value AND backup.FREQ1 AND Backup.FREQ2) (
   SELECT backup.Value, backup.FREQ1, backup.FREQ2, backup.CAT
   FROM backup
   WHERE ((backup.[Part Number]) ="xyz") 
);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

JR

Comment: Either do EXISTS instead of IN, or do a self join.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need below query -

```
SELECT B1.[Part Number], B1.Value, B1.FreqL, B1.FreqH
FROM backup B1
JOIN (SELECT Value, FREQ1 , FREQ2
      FROM backup
      WHERE [Part Number] ="xyz") B2 ON B1.Value = B2.Value
                                     AND B1.FREQ1 = B2.FREQ1 
                                     AND B1.FREQ2 = B2.FREQ2;
```

Comment: I like the join better than the exists.  (If you don't have the  tuples option like in db2)

Answer (score 0):

A typical method uses `exists`:

```
SELECT b.[Part Number], b.Value, b.FreqL, b.FreqH
FROM backup b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM backup b2
              WHERE b2.[Part Number] = 'xyz' AND
                    b2.Value = b.Value AND
                    b2.FREQ1 = b.FREQ1 AND 
                    b2.FREQ2 = b.FREQ2
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say your platform, in DB2 tuples work -- like this:

```
SELECT backup.[Part Number], backup.Value, backup.FreqL, backup.FreqH
FROM backup 
WHERE (backup.Value, backup.FREQ1, Backup.FREQ2) = (
   SELECT backup.Value, backup.FREQ1, backup.FREQ2
   FROM backup
   WHERE ((backup.[Part Number]) ="xyz") 
);
```